# How to decipher time in console

Tags: console, time

I'm reading my console logs and trying to figure out how to interpret the time stamp that console displays:

```
Time 1332251808
TimeNanoSec 72951500
```

I also have another time stamp that reads:

```
Time 1232456005
```

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are Unix time stamps, ie, the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1 1970):

```
# date -d @1332251808
Tue Mar 20 13:56:48 GMT 2012

# date -d @0
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 GMT 1970
```

Comment: thanks — that makes sense; is there an equivalent command to date -d for the nano seconds?

Comment: ↳ does the command above display the time or set it? on my console the command to display the number of seconds since epoch is `date -r 1332251808` resulting in `Tue Mar 20 06:56:48 MST 2012`

Comment: For me it displays, my `-r` option is to get the last modification date of a file. 72951500 nano seconds is 0.072951500 seconds, so you can just add them on, either before or after calling `date`.